# Outlook Rules move mail from 1 inbox to another

Tags: exchange, outlook

I have 2 mailboxes setup in outlook, both are exchange mail. I would like to set up a rule to run so when i receive a new email from the 2nd inbox to forward it to my primary inbox?

It seems that my rules i have setup dont run against the 2nd inbox unless i manually tell them to by clicking the 'Run Rules' now option and selecting the 2nd inboxes folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general Oulook will only run rules automatically on your primary inbox. You can get round this by setting up the rules for your second inbox to run on the server, rather than in Outlook. To do this you will need to connect to that inbox in its own Outlook profile, with it as the primary inbox.